# Storing pandas DataFrames in SQLAlchemy models

Tags: python, pandas, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm building a flask application that allows users to upload CSV files (with varying columns), preview uploaded files, generate summary statistics, perform complex transformations/aggregations (sometimes via Celery jobs), and then export the modified data. The uploaded file is being read into a pandas DataFrame, which allows me to elegantly handle most of the complicated data work.

I'd like these DataFrames along with associated metadata (time uploaded, ID of user uploading the file, etc.) to persist and be available for multiple users to pass around to various views. However, I'm not sure how best to incorporate the data into my SQLAlchemy models (I'm using PostgreSQL on the backend).

Three approaches I've considered:

- Cramming the DataFrame into a `PickleType` and storing it directly in the DB. This seems to be the most straightforward solution, but means I'll be sticking large binary objects into the database.
- Pickling the DataFrame, writing it to the filesystem, and storing the path as a string in the model. This keeps the database small but adds some complexity when backing up the database and allowing users to do things like delete previously uploaded files.
- Converting the DataFrame to JSON (`DataFrame.to_json()`) and storing it as a `json` type (maps to PostgreSQL's `json` type). This adds the overhead of parsing JSON each time the DataFrame is accessed, but it also allows the data to be manipulated directly via [PostgreSQL JSON operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html).

Given the advantages and drawbacks of each (including those I'm unaware of), is there a preferred way to incorporate pandas DataFrames into SQLAlchemy models?

Comment: Is writing each dataframe itself to a seperate postgresql table an option? (using `to_sql` http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: Hmm...I could try that too (using a custom to_sql method since PostgreSQL isn't yet supported). I could generate the names of those tables dynamically and track them separate model along with associated metadata. Then, I could pull the table name from that object when I need to reference it and read it back into a data frame from the table. I wonder what advantage that would hold over the other methods?

Comment: sqlachemy support will be coming to `to_sql` in version 14.0 (expected to be released some time in May 2014). Haven't tried it in the dev version, but could be an interesting option.

Comment: Indeed, in development version PostgreSQL will be supported for writing to sql via sqlalchemy. So you could try the development version, or a first release candidate will probably released next week. If you only want to store the data, I think you should best do some comparisons (of eg performance) of your different options. Using `to_sql` you have of course the advantage of being able to directly access the data in postgresql (query parts of the dataframes, other sql manipulations, etc), but I don't know if you need that.

Comment: what did you end up doing?

Comment: @Quant -- To be honest, we ended up tabling the project, but it's sure to come up again in the next few months, at which point I'll wind up benchmarking a few different solutions. I'm leaning towards converting the DataFrame to JSON and cramming it in a single JSON field, so I can leverage the benefits of the SQLAlchemy model (including Flask-Admin views).

Answer (score 6):

Go towards the JSON and PostgreSQL solution. I am on a Pandas project that started with the Pickle on file system, and loaded the data into to an class object for the data processing with pandas. However, as the data became large, we played with SQLAlchemy / SQLite3. Now, we are finding that working with SQLAlchemy / PostgreSQL is even better. I think our next step will be JSON.
Have fun! Pandas rocks!